# How to know if RecyclerView item is partially visible or completely visible when user click on it?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to enable click listener on RecyclerView item only if it is completely visible otherwise click listener should not work. Is there any way to detect whether an adapter item is completely visible or not when user click on it?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for can be found [here](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/blob/master/src/org/thoughtcrime/securesms/giph/util/RecyclerViewPositionHelper.java)

Answer (score -1):

You could make some logic using LayoutManager api to get last completely visible item position in RecyclerView onScrolled method:

```
((LinearLayoutManager) vYourRecycler.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

From the documentation: Returns the adapter position of the last fully visible view. This position does not include adapter changes that were dispatched after the last layout pass.

Comment: The requirement is something different. I need to detect whether an item is completely visible or not when user click on it.

Comment: That is why I said you have to create your own logic for it, Just check the Adapter position on which user clicked and the last completely visible position and create a logic accordingly.